# limitation for n in git show HEAD^n or git show HEAD~n

Tags: git

Is there any limitation for n in `git show HEAD^n` or `git show HEAD~n` commands? when I run `git show HEAD^4` it gives me `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^4': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` error while running `git show HEAD^^^^` shows me the corresponding commit.

Comment: `HEAD^^^^` is equivalent to `HEAD~4`, not `HEAD^4`.

Comment: in HEAD^n , n cannot be greater than 2 and HEAD^2 is only the case when the HEAD is pointing to a result of a merge

Comment: n can also be greater than 2 in HEAD^n, if a commit has more than 2 parents.

Comment: @amiref a commit can have more than two parents, so n can be greater than 2. It’s not common though.